# Как идентифицировать пользователя на другом домене?

Tags: php, идентификация

Например есть два сайта site1.ru и site2.ru. Пользователь заходит на site1.ru, тут нужно его как-то так запомнить, чтобы при заходе пользователя на site2.ru, мы бы могли точно определить что это этот же пользователь. Т.е. какой-то идентификатор оставить при посещении site1.ru (где его можно поставить?)

На первом домене можно использовать js, а вот на втором сайте пользователь должен сразу определиться на уровне php.

Без учета IP-адреса. Адрес site2.ru изначально может быть не известен (при заходе на site1.ru). Оба сайта могут находиться на одном хостинге.

Это возможно?)

Comment: Нет (буквыбуквы)

Answer (score 1):

Я лично не поддерживаю fingerprint, поэтому предложу свой вариант как можно это провернуть.

Можно сделать так: На site1.ru будет js код(Возможно jQuery), он будет посылать XMLHttpRequest сайту site2.ru, а на сайте site2.ru будет соответсвующий код для принятия и обработки запроса(JSON или подобного типа) пользователя(Главное чтобы со стороны клиента запрос который отправляется не блокировался и можно было бы синхронизировать site1.ru и site2.ru), в итоге site1.ru получит запрос от пользователя и site2.ru также получит этот запрос и сохранит его вместе с site1.ru, всё это сохранится в общую датабазу синхронизированную между site1.ru и site2.ru, а датабаза будет находиться на каком-то из сайтов.

Answer (score 0):

На первом сайте записываете fingerprint в базу. На втором удаленно обращаетесь в базу первого сайта

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Fingerprint, как понял, можно собрать только используя js. 
Т.е. на втором сайте опять же через js нужно их собрать для сверки.. 
Получается что на уровне сервера сверить, это невозможно..